# How do I edit the label for Appearance in the Wordpress Admin backend?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to rename the Appearance label in Wordpress to Themes but I can't get it done.

I've managed to change other menu items but I can't find anything on this.

Any idea how?

I thought I could follow the same lines as changing the Posts menu but it doesn't work as it doesn't know what to change.

```
function change_appearance_menu_label() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[1][0] = 'Themes';
    echo '';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_appearance_menu_label' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_appearance_menu_label' );
function change_appearance_menu_label( $translated ) 
{  
    $translated = str_replace( 'Appearance', 'Themes', $translated );
    return $translated;
}
```